# How can I effectively "extend" the functionality of a function in sub-traits?

Tags: inheritance, rust, traits

Say I need to model some living things. All living things need to do stuff:

```rust
trait LivingThing {
    fn do_stuff(&self);
}
```

I might have sub-traits like animals and plants that do different things. Say I model an animal like this:

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn do_other_stuff(&self);
    fn food(&self) {
        println!("Looking for food!");
    }
}

impl LivingThing for dyn Animal {
    fn do_stuff(&self) {
        self.food();
        self.do_other_stuff();
    }
}
```

The `food` function does not need `self` at the moment, but I am just trying to keep things simple here. The `do_other_stuff` function exists to ensure sub-traits can add their own functionality which is automatically called when calling the `do_stuff` function. Like a human, for example:

```rust
struct Human {}

impl Animal for Human {
    fn do_other_stuff(&self) {
        println!("Taking a shower!");
    }
}
```

I can now do this to automatically have the `Human` functionality as well as the `Animal` functionality.

```rust
let some_human = Human {};
LivingThing::do_stuff(&some_human as &dyn Animal);
// Prints: Looking for food!
//         Taking a shower!
```

What I dislike about this is that I can't do this

```rust
let some_human = Human {};
some_human.do_stuff();
```

because `Human` doesn't implement the `LivingThing` trait. But I feel like there is no conflict because Human implements `Animal` which implements `LivingThing`. Sure, `Human` could implement 10 different traits that all implement `LivingThing` but if there is just one implementation it should be clear what I am trying to do. Do I just have to live with this? Or is there a better way to add to the functionality of `do_stuff` in sub-traits?

What I have done until now is invert the model: Have `Human` implement `LivingThing` and `Animal` and have a trait-bound for `Animal: LivingThing`. The issue is, that I need to remember to call the `Animal`'s `food` function from the `Human` which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your other option would be to use generics to implement  `LivingThing` for all types that implement `Animal`

```
impl<T> LivingThing for T
where T: Animal {
    fn do_stuff(&self) {
        self.food();
        self.do_other_stuff();
    }
}
```

However, until [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) is stabilized, this approach means directly implementing `LivingThing` on any type that implements `Animal` (such as `Human`) will cause an implementation conflict.